# Is it possible to change the color of YouTube's most watched bar using Tampermonkey?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to change the color of the youtube most watched bar with tampermonkey?

I want to change the color of the bar and the only thing I can do is finding the element and change it within inspect element, the element is.

class="ytp-heat-map-graph" clip-path="url(#3)" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.2" height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0"

And I have no idea how to replace this with tampermonkey or make it read it in the program.